# Provider recursion question

Tags: java, recursion, factory, guice, provider

So, I have class `Bar` that should contains factory of Bars.

```
class Bar {
    Collection<Bar> children;
    Bar(BarFactory factory, Foo1 foo, Foo2 foo2){

    }
    addChild(Foo1 foo1){
         children.add(factory.create(foo1));
    }
}
class BarFactory {
    Bar create(Foo1 foo1);
}
```

The problem in describing BarFactory. There are specific logic with dependencies from other objects. I've tried to use `@Provides` mechanism, like

```
@Provides
BarFactory provideLogicElementPresenterFactory(Dependence d){
    final BarFactory f = new BarFactory(){  
        @Override
        public Bar create(Foo1 foo1) {
            Foo2 foo2 = null;//some logic
            return new Bar(/*how pass factory here?*/f, foo1, foo2);
        }
    };
    return f;
}
```

How to describe such recursive structure or there is alternative solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `f` in when invoking the `Bar` constructor.

Comment: Yeah. I should definitely go sleep) Thanks a lot.